# R: Replace missing character values in one row for specific columns based on unique ID - doesn't work for actual data

Tags: r

I am trying to take the value from the row above and have it fill in the row below if blank or NA grouped on the record_id.

```
df <- data.frame(
  record_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3),
  hh_id = c(12,12,12,1,1,1,3),
  interviewer_code= c(1, "", "", 4, "", "", 12),
  village= c("Village B", "", "", "Village C", "", "", "Village C"))
```

I tried this code, and it works for this example dataset

```
df$village[df$village == ""] <- NA
new_df <- na.locf(df)
```

However, when I try it with my actual data (68 columns), all the data in all the rows disappear. I am not sure what could be causing the issue in my actual data?

Comment: From the docs of `na.locf()`: "Note that if a multi-column zoo object has a column entirely composed of NA then with na.rm = TRUE, the default, the above implies that the resulting object will have zero rows. Use na.rm = FALSE to preserve the NA values instead." - could that be it?

Comment: That was it! Thank you Paul!